# allow.cartesian error even when I have no duplicates

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table` objects like this:

**profile table**

```
> profile
                id cat_id
    1: -HcDR55tvHU      1
    2: -SZ3w0Vs_Ww      1
    3: -UGaEjF4yPo      1
    4: -iJG24SZJ20      1
    5: -veBNWFcvcI      1
   ---                   
45832: zyOY8uqweaA     29
45833: zyR1T15yl58     29
45834: zyu8OPWhJoA     29
45835: zzN9id8zUcs     29
45836: zzjpVRq8bXM     29

> key(profile)
[1] "cat_id"
```

**category table**

```
> head(cat)
   id         category
1:  1 Film & Animation
2:  2 Autos & Vehicles
3: 10            Music
4: 15   Pets & Animals
5: 17           Sports
6: 18     Short Movies

> key(cat)
[1] "id"
```

I am trying to join the two tables and the expected output should be like this:

```
                id cat_id         category
    1: -HcDR55tvHU      1 Film & Animation
    2: -SZ3w0Vs_Ww      1 Film & Animation
    3: -UGaEjF4yPo      1 Film & Animation
    4: -iJG24SZJ20      1 Film & Animation
    5: -veBNWFcvcI      1 Film & Animation
   ---                   
45832: zyOY8uqweaA     29      bla bla bla
45833: zyR1T15yl58     29      bla bla bla
45834: zyu8OPWhJoA     29      bla bla bla
45835: zzN9id8zUcs     29      bla bla bla
45836: zzjpVRq8bXM     29      bla bla bla
```

When I do `data <- profile[cat]`, I get this weird error of duplicate keys:

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 45853 rows; more than 45836 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)).
Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over
and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so
that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to
proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error
message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
```

Then I tried something really simple, which I believe is the same:

```
> test <- data.table("x"=rep(1:5, each=10), "y"=rnorm(50))
> test2 <- data.table("id"=1:5, "name"=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
> setkey(test, x)
> setkey(test2, id)
> test[test2]
    x           y name
 1: 1  0.85078369    a
 2: 1 -0.56896642    a
 3: 1 -0.12108724    a
 4: 1  0.09204798    a
 5: 1 -1.48852315    a
 6: 1  0.18614002    a
```

Why does the latter work but not the former?

Comment: That error message should be self-explanatory - you have duplicate keys in `cat`. Either remove the duplicates or add `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

Comment: @eddi, I did check that part actually. The output for `sum(duplicated(cat$id))` is `0`.

Comment: @eddi To your point, `allow.cartesian = TRUE` will work, but I really would like to understand why my second example doesn't need it. Aren't they the same case?

Comment: @Boxuan, please try installing the latest devel version (1.9.5) from the github project page.. We've fixed some 'allow.cartesian' cases in there. Why do you find the error message "weird" :O?

Comment: @Arun I should really change the title. It is misleading. I mentioned "weird", because I don't understand why my first example failed, but second one worked.

Comment: Since I don't have access to your data that's causing the error, I can only guess. And my guess is that (assuming `i` doesn't have duplicates like you show in comment) `i` has some additional values that are not in `x`, and that results in more rows.. And yes, that shouldn't be an error, and this has been fixed in 1.9.5. And regarding your title, it's not necessarily misleading, but not very useful for people who will search later. If it's indeed the case I explain, you could edit the title as "allow.cartesian error even when i has no duplicates"..

Comment: @Arun Thanks for your input! I have changed the title. Do you mind submitting an answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer yet. Like I said, I don't have the data to test. What do you think is the answer?